# Can't access ** variable as an array from a struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

First off this is a difficult question to articulate as I'm not greatly familiar with C and I have searched around but I'm also not familiar with the lingo for C. Also the code compiles fine without any warnings or errors.

What I am trying to do?

I am trying to access the items variable as an array from an instance of the HashTable struct.

These are the structs I'm using:

```
typedef struct
{
    char *word;
    int count;
} Item;

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    size_t uniques;
    Item **items;
} HashTable;
```

My program breaks when I hit a piece of code that attempts to access the variables in the items array:

```
hashTable->items[index]->word
```

or

```
hashTable->items[index]->count
```

This is the intializer:

```
HashTable *hashTable_new (int size)
{
    HashTable *hashTable = calloc (1, sizeof (HashTable));
    hashTable->size = size;
    hashTable->uniques = 0;
    hashTable->items = calloc (size, sizeof (Item));

    return hashTable;
}
```

Comment: replace `**` with `*`

Comment: Doesn't work, logically I thought it might but that causes errors.

Comment: Using `Item *items;` would work the same but involve a lot less allocation. You have all your items side by side in memory, instead of having lots of little chunks all over the place.

Comment: Why do you use calloc for this? Wouldn't malloc be enough?

Comment: @MattMcNabb I tried changing my code to 'Item *items;' and got this any where I tried to access items like I wanted to:

[Error] invalid type argument of '->' (have 'Item')

Comment: @BuellaGábor I need to initialize the count variables to 0 so I use calloc, I've changed some of it now though to use malloc where I know I don't need it.

Comment: use `.` to access struct members instead of `->`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line before the return command should probably be:

```
hashTable->items = calloc (size, sizeof(Item *));
```

You are allocating an array of pointers to *Item*. So that would be the correct way of doing so.
However, you still have to iterate the array somewhere and then initialize every item, before you can reference them. Something as such:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < hashTable->size; ++i)
{
    hashTable->items[i] = malloc(sizeof(Item));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes a lot of sense I can't believe I overlooked it

Answer (score 1):

> hashTable->items = calloc (size, sizeof (Item));

In the above line what you are trying to do is creating a `size` no of items. which is pointed by a pointer of type  `hashTable->items` for which it need not be a double pointer if your traversing the struct.

change `Item **items;` to `Item *items;`

If you want memory of each Item struct to stored and one more pointer pointing to the array of pointers.change the first line to

hashTable->items = calloc (size, sizeof(Item *)); // create size no of pointers

and then create each of the Item struct in loop.

```
 for (size_t i = 0; i < hashTable->size; ++i)
 {
      hashTable->items[i] = calloc(1,sizeof(Item));
 }
```